# form to open a text file for view in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm required to create a user form like the one in the picture

[image]

I need to open a file with an extension of .txt from excel using VBA and also the button provided.

After selecting the file, when i press start it will open the file.

I was given some codes done by previously but was not working.

will appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks!

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Unload Me 'Cancellation command
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'start button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Summary").Select

    Call Transposer("Summary Transpose")

    Sheets("Failing Patterns").Select

    Call Transposer("Failing Patterns Transpose")

    Me.Status = "Status: Finished"

    Me.Error = ""

    'Make sure the screen updates before the end


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub


Public Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub testFinder_Click()

    Me.testDirectory.Value = Application.GetOpenFilename

End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Select the Text File Put this code in the testFinder_Click()

```
Private Sub testFinder_Click()
    Dim fileToOpen

    fileToOpen = Application _
    .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub

    testDirectory.Value = fileToOpen
End Sub
```

To open the text file you can use this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    '
    '~~> Rest of Code
    '
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=testDirectory.Value, Origin:=437, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    '
    '~~> Rest of Code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: I am referring to your Transposer() and other code that you have above.

Comment: i'm not very sure what you mean by the 'rest of code' in the 2nd portion... and there is a runtime 424 error and it showed the error is at testDirectory.Value ...

Comment: What is the name of the textbox? Is it not "testDirectory"?

Comment: oh! I understand what you meant.. ok thanks! But for some reason there are still errors at my code (the transposer part) to start the running of the code. There was an compile error.

Comment: if i'm not wrong, transposer is used to transpose the text files... but for some reason it isnt working.. btw, i will be away for awhile, may not reply you immediately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat when you are back](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7943/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1204868)